# Excel. copy text string and number of repeats to new columns

Tags: vba, excel-formula

Given two columns (A and B), one with a text and one with an integer, such as:

```
A   |   B
pen |   3
pen |   5
```

How could I fill the columns C, D, E [...] with the concatenation of the given string on each row with all integers starting from 1 until the specified number?

The desired output for the given example would be:

```
A    |  B  |  C      |  D      |  E      |  F      |  G
pen  |  3  |  pen01  |  pen02  |  pen03  |         |
pen  |  5  |  pen01  |  pen02  |  pen03  |  pen04  |  pen05
```

Comment: there are two solutions to your question below - one vba, and one formula - were either of them able to solve your problem? If not, and you solved it yourself, can you share your answer below?

Whatever solution worked for you, can you mark it as correct to close the question? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

With a simple vba sub this can be achieved:

```
Sub CreateValues
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim LastRow as Long: LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            Max_Num = .Cells(i, 2)
            For j = 1 to Max_Num
                .Cells(i, j + 2) = .Cells(i, 1) & Format(j, "00")
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a formula solution without needing to resort to VBA, you can use this formula in `C1` and drag in both dimensions:

`=IF(COLUMNS($C1:C1)<=$B1,CONCATENATE($A1,TEXT(COLUMNS($C1:C1),"00")),"")`